# Force change default initial save location of all programs to custom folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems, save-as

Many programs often default the save destination location to the standard Libraries/XYZ folder which is the last place I want to save anything (due to sensible backup reasons).

Some programs go a step further and force you to that location within the same program session (Classic Media Player springs to mind) even if you've saved a file elsewhere just a minute beforehand.

Other programs allow you to define this location, but is there a way to force Windows to change the location of any program to a destination of your choice, regardless of what each program dictates?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you're looking for, but symbolic links have proven useful to me in the past. For instance, many programs are hardcoded to store things in APPDATA but I generally don't want all of this "data" on my "system" sdd. Here, symbolic links come in handy. It can be quirky, and I wouldn't recommend symlinking your entire appdata folder, do it individually on a program by program basis. Of course I would also suggest letting the developer of said program know of your desire for such things.

In your case of some programs not remembering where you last saved a file, when it opens SaveFileDialog again (even in the same session), I'm not sure you can do much about that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx